# How Delphi object inspector grey some properties?

Tags: delphi

Recently I found that Delphi object inspector displays some properties in grey. Here is an example:

[image: Object Inspector grayed properties Example]

I wonder what does it mean? How such properties are defined? I did not find any differences in definition of let's say **DSHostname** and **ProxyHost**. But as you can see **DSHostname** is displayed normally and **ProxyHost** in grey.

Here is a relevant declaration of properties in question:

```
  /// <summary>The host to proxy requests through, or empty string to not use a proxy.</summary>
  property ProxyHost: string read FProxyHost write FProxyHost;
  /// <summary>The port on the proxy host to proxy requests through. Ignored if DSProxyHost isn't set.
  /// </summary>
  [Default(8888)]
  property ProxyPort: Integer read FProxyPort write FProxyPort default 8888;
  /// <summary>The user name for authentication with the specified proxy.</summary>
  property ProxyUsername: string read FProxyUsername write FProxyUsername;
  /// <summary>The password for authentication with the specified proxy.</summary>
  property ProxyPassword: string read FProxyPassword write FProxyPassword;
```

Comment: A link to documentation would certainly help.

Comment: @LURD , what kind of documentation are you asking for?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Datasnap.DSCommon.TDSClientCallbackChannelManager_Properties

Comment: Something seems to be defining them as read-only, although their declaration doesn't make them so.

Comment: Apparently Datasnap design-time package lacks full source - I cannot find registration unit amongst installed sources.

Comment: My guess (and this is only a guess) is that the design-time package is registering a property editor that marks the properties as read-only, by overriding the  `TPropertyEditor.GetAttributes()` method to return the `paReadOnly` flag.

Comment: maybe a coincidence, all quoted properties do not have getter nor setter method and basically are merely pseudonyms for a variable

Comment: I wonder if those four properties are always greyed out, or only if certain conditions apply. Can the Object Inspector change this dynamically? Can the Object Inspector be told to update its display for these properties?

Comment: @Remy, worth to be saved as an answer, methinks.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I don't know, but if you figure it out, maybe you could comment on [this question](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222275) on the Embarcadero forum.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'll take a look, this week.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I got a proof that **Remy Lebeau** was right in his guess. I made a descendant of **TDSClientCallbackChannelManager** which has published property **TestProxyHost**. This property does nothing but mirroring **ProxyHost** in Get and Set. Here is the full code for the component:

```
unit uTestCallbackChannelManager;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSCommon;

type
  TTestCallbackChannelManager = class(TDSClientCallbackChannelManager)
  private
    function GetTestProxyHost: string;
    procedure SetTestProxyHost(const Value: string);
  published
    property TestProxyHost: string read GetTestProxyHost write SetTestProxyHost;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TTestCallbackChannelManager]);
end;

{ TTestCallbackChannelManager }

function TTestCallbackChannelManager.GetTestProxyHost: string;
begin
  Result := ProxyHost;
end;

procedure TTestCallbackChannelManager.SetTestProxyHost(const Value: string);
begin
  ProxyHost := Value;
end;

end.
```

After I installed **TTestCallbackChannelManager** into component palette I dropped in on a form in a test project.

In Object Inspector the **ProxyHost** property is displayed in grey and **TestProxyHost** as normal. Now if I change **TestProxyHost** then **ProxyHost** is changed as well. Here is a screenshot:

[image: ProxyHost property is changed]

This means:

1. RTTI information of **ProxyHost** property **was not altered** in any way and it is indeed a read/write property in both design- and run-time.
2. The only way to achieve such behavior is on the **Property Editor** level. The **Property Editor** registered for this particular **property name** in **this** component type "tells" Object Inspector "Hey, I can not set this property for you" (but an other code can do it directly).
3. This also explains why if I uncheck "Show read only properties" flag in Object Inspector options **ProxyHost** (and 3 related properties) are still shown in the Object Inspector. It is because of Object Inspector reads the properties from dfm as read/write and then creates Property Editors for them and once Property Editor says it can't write the property they are shaded in grey (but still shown as Property Editor is already created).

The only problem is what logic behind the Property Editor? When the properties become available and how to use them? It looks like the properties are introduced very recently in xe10 or a bit earlier. And Embarcadero provides no documentation about these properties (at least for now I could not find any). **But this is a subject of separate question.** I suspect that support for these properties has not been tested (or may be not implemented) yet and so they are intended for use in future releases.